# Dropdown menu not inherit its parent position

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown, antd

```
     <div className="inner-dark-section">
        <div
          className="search-section"
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            position: "sticky",
            top: "0",
            zIndex: 10,
            backgroundColor: "#1b1b1b",
            paddingTop: "25px",
          }}
        >
          <RepSearch queryProcessor={processQuery} currQuery={currQuery} />
        </div>
      </div>
```

have two dropdowns (antd) in `ResSearch` component but the dropdown menu is not inherited it parent position as it's not `sticky` when scrolled it scrolled over `RepSearch` elements.

```
.ant-select-dropdown {
  background-color: $util-dropdown;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5px rgba(91, 91, 91, 0.5),
    0 9px 28px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: fixed;
}
```

how to make dropdown menu moves with the `RepSearch` component when it scroll

Comment: As stated in the documentation if you find that the drop-down menu scrolls with the page, please try to use `getPopupContainer = {triggerNode => triggerNode.parentElement}` to fix the drop-down popup rendering.

Comment: it's worked, post it as an asnwer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation if you find that the drop-down menu scrolls with the page, please try to use
`getPopupContainer = {triggerNode => triggerNode.parentElement}`
to fix the drop-down popup rendering.